# Google Spreadsheets | How to get the first and last active cell in a range, and then return a cell offset from that cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gantt-chart

I want to try to automate a very tedious process that I've been stuck with for a while now in my Gantt charts.

I can get the range that I want to pull from, but what I really need are cells offset from that range corresponding with the first and last active cells in the range.

[image: Screenshot of what I am trying to describe]

Columns B and C are what I need automated. They represent Row 1's values on the first and last active cell per row.

I'm familiar with how to do the opposite, to populate a range with something based on first and last values of column B/C. "x" however in my sheets is often different values which feed into other sources of code and are often changed by people other than myself, so I don't have many options on changing my workflow like this.

Happy to provide any additional info, a solution in cell formulas or in scripts is perfectly fine, scripts would be actually be preferable but I'd be happy with either. Thanks for reading!

Comment: I suggest that you share a more realistic sample. It's difficult to know from what you've posted what facets are literal and which are just placeholders. For instance, are there really numbers (e.g., 1, 2, 3...) placed above the rightmost columns? Will the "x" values always be grouped together with no breaks between them every (e.g., always `xxx` and never `x  x`)? Are there only ever five columns that might contain the "x" data, or are there actually more? And will that number of columns grow over time, or is it fixed? Formulas are written around specifics, and we don't have many yet.

Comment: Take a look at: `getDataRegion:`https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdataregiondimension

Comment: Adam, this can all be done with formulas instead of script. But you haven't responded to my request and questions here (though I see you've responded to others). If you are not interested in my help (or anyone else's in the future), please at least acknowledge that you've read all comments left by the volunteers here who have invested time in trying to help you.

Comment: Hey Erik! So sorry I missed your comment. I straight up just did not see it and only just now noticed it in an email notification- I definitely get what you mean by needing a more realistic sample, I see the miscommunication my screenshot may have created. I will try to craft a response to your question later today if time allows, I have been basically just been eating sleeping and working all week so far so apologies if I made it seem like I intentionally ignored you, definitely was not the case.

Comment: Adam, I'll assume that you no longer want help here since, again, you haven't responded for a week. Hope you found what you were after.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done pretty easy with `array.findIndex()` method. Here is the example:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var [header, ...rows] = range.getValues();

  var new_rows = [];

  for (var row of rows) {
    var [a, b, c, d, ...etc] = row;
    b = get_first_not_empty_cell_from(etc);
    c = get_last_not_empty_cell_from(etc);
    new_rows.push([a, b, c, d, ...etc]);
  }

  console.log(new_rows);

  range.setValues([header, ...new_rows]);
}

function get_first_not_empty_cell_from(array) {
  var index = array.findIndex(x => x != '') + 1;
  return index;
}

function get_last_not_empty_cell_from(array) {
  var index = array.slice().reverse().findIndex(x => x != '');
  return array.length - index;
}
```

[image]

**Reference:**

- [array.findIndex(](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex))

**Update**

Here is the updated variant of the code:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var [header, row2, ...rows] = range.getValues(); // <-- skip row 2

  var new_rows = [];

  for (var row of rows) {
    var [a, b, c, d, ...etc] = row;
    b = header[get_first_index(etc) + 3];  // <-- value from header
    c = header[get_last_index(etc) + 3];   // <-- value from header
    new_rows.push([a, b, c, d, ...etc]);
  }

  console.log(new_rows);

  range.setValues([header, row2, ...new_rows]); // <-- add row 2
}

function get_first_index(array) {
  var index = array.findIndex(x => x != '') + 1;
  return index;
}

function get_last_index(array) {
  var index = array.slice().reverse().findIndex(x => x != '');
  return array.length - index;
}
```

Basically this is all the same, but now it puts values from the cells of the first row instead of the column indexes. And it skips the second empty row.

Just in case, the same code in the short 'functional' style:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var [header, row2, ...rows] = range.getValues();

  const first = ar => ar.findIndex(x => x != '') + 1;
  const last = ar => ar.length - ar.slice().reverse().findIndex(x => x != '');

  var new_rows = rows.map(([a, b, c, d, ...etc]) => 
    [a, header[first(etc) + 3], header[last(etc) + 3], d, ...etc]);

  console.log(new_rows);

  range.setValues([header, row2, ...new_rows]);
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering my question. This is almost enough to achieve what I am trying to automate, but I see now that my example created the wrong impression of what I am trying to place in columns B/C. I'm trying to take the values in row 1 and paste them in column B/C regardless of the contents of the cells in row 1. The code you've written works perfectly when row 1 is simply 1, 2, 3, 4 etc, but in my actual charts row 1 is filled with dates. Apologies for that.

The only other thing I can't understand in your code is stopping numbers from pasting into header rows, like row 2.

Comment: Okay, I've just added the updated version of the code. It puts values from the row1 to B/C columns. And it skips row2.